# IntelliJ IDEA: Boolean method XX is always inverted

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I am getting warning "  Boolean method   is always inverted " on running lint in  IntelliJ. I have several similar warnings in my codebase. Which basic coding style, am I missing?

```
public static boolean isBlueToothEnabled(){
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(bluetoothAdapter != null)
        return bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
    return  false;
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try to return `false` if `bluetoothAdapter` is null otherwise return the output of `isEnabled()`

```
public static boolean isBlueToothEnabled(){
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(bluetoothAdapter == null){
        return false;
    }
    return bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
}
```

Read more:

> In Clean Code, Robert Martin writes, “Negatives are just a bit harder
>   to understand than positives. So, when possible, conditionals should
>   be expressed as positives.” (Martin, [G29]). IntelliJ IDEA has three
>   inspections to help you stay positive.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/the-inspection-connection-issue-2/
(Entry #4 Avoiding negative Conditionals)

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/invert-boolean.html

Comment: but what is the idea/purpose in switching the return value (I dont get it from the link you posted).

Comment: This immediately leads to the question: how to disable that inspection.

Comment: this case looks valid. however, i have a one line method of this form: `validationMessages.stream().anyMatch(m -> m.level() == Level.ERROR);` and i get that same warning. 

doesn't make sense to me here.

Comment: @dtc
I did not really spend much time on that, but could you avoid that by usind noneMatch instead of anyMatch?
Imho that should resolve the warning since your method woud return true if there is not error instead of true if there is an error. Let me know what you think.

Comment: that does resolve the warning but that simply changes the logic and affects the method name i have: "hasErrors"

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("BooleanMethodIsAlwaysInverted")`

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya you saved my day :)

Comment: Think of it from a caller perspective. To check an invalid email, You can call !x.isValidEmail() (TRUE by negation) or x.isInvalidEmail() (True by default). The second is preferred.

Answer (score 29):

**Summary: Method always called like !method(). It's more efficient to have less number of computation. Refactor the method and return oppositely and call the method without (!)**

---

**Why it happens**

If we have a method `foo()`

```
    boolean foo()
    {
        if(condition == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

And is only called like `!foo()`,

```
    class A
    {
        if(!foo())
            do something;
        ...
        if(!foo())
            do something else;
    }
```

Because we only call `!foo()` and did not call `foo()`.

The warning asks us to use `foo()` in a positive way.

**Remove the warning**

By inverting the return value of the method foo(),

```
    boolean foo()
    {
        if(condition == true)
            return **false**;
        else
            return **true**;
    }
```

Now call the method

```
    class A
    {
        if(foo())
            do the same thing;
    }
```

Comment: That's great but is this just to remove warning? Any practical benefits? Like performance or something else, perhaps?

Comment: Negligible but unnecessary Overhead for negating the result. If you have method calls which negates results more often than not, you have the same negation overhead

Comment: "It's more efficient to have ..." shouldn't this performance problem be handled at the compiler-level?

Comment: @Hzzkygcs It is. The compiler simply replaces an `ifne` with an `ifeq` instruction in this case, and even in more complicated expressions like `if (!foo() || bar())`.

Answer (score 6):

I must say that there are cases where I think this warning isn't even fixable in a reasonable way. Take for example code looking like this:

```
boolean getInfo(Info info) {
    // Retrieve some info that can fail so the function returns true or false
}

void func() {
    Info info;

    if (!getInfo(info)) {
        // Failed; handle error, early out
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff

    if (!getInfo(info)) {
        // Failed; handle error, early out
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff

    if (!getInfo(info)) {
        // Failed; handle error, early out
        return;
    }

    // Do final calculations
}
```

What to do in a case like this? Rename the function to `notGetInfo()`? `getDesinformation()`? Don't early out of the function on failure resulting in a growing tree of brackets?

Comment: Agreed. For the sake of readability, this pattern is far better... at least for `boolean` returns. When I'm looking at the class' methods, it makes far more sense to see a method named `getInfo` than a `failedToGetInfo` or `getInfoFailure` method. It would confuse me as to the method's primary purpose; does it do something, or does it check for failure? On the other hand, in this case one could say it's more elegant (and still very readable) to have `void getInfo()`, and _throw Exceptions_ on failure, with an explanation to be found in a stack trace, rather than returning a vague boolean.

Comment: This is a good solution, although if one expects `getInfo` to fail often then one have to consider the very high cost of exceptions in java.

Answer (score 0):

For simplify, See the code below:

```
public boolean isBoy(int sex){ return sex == boy};

if(!isBoy(sex)){ // todo}

If do so, it called inverted. How to solve? see the other code below:

public boolean isGirl(int sex){ return sex == girl};

if(isGirl(sex)){ // todo}
```

Because you need to judge the condition whether is a girl, So that you should avoid to judge whether is a boy and put a '!'.